# How to get the most recent record for a user within a day over a period of time

Tags: sql

I have a dataset where I record the different activities for a user over a period of time, so I have multiple users with several activities over different days.

I'm looking for all the users that have submitted event B for the 15th and the 16th, and then want to pull only the last occurrence of event B in case more than one exists.

Example data set:

```
User Event Event_Date Event_Time
==== ===== ========== =================================
  1   A    15-May-13  15-MAY-13 05.46.20.000000000 AM
  2   A    15-May-13  15-MAY-13 09.33.22.000000000 AM
  3   A    15-May-13  15-MAY-13 09.47.50.000000000 AM
  4   A    15-May-13  15-MAY-13 09.59.53.000000000 AM
  5   A    15-May-13  15-MAY-13 10.12.25.000000000 AM
  1   B    15-May-13  15-MAY-13 05.46.20.000000000 AM
  1   B    15-May-13  15-MAY-13 09.33.22.000000000 AM
**1   B    15-May-13  15-MAY-13 09.47.50.000000000 AM**
**3   B    15-May-13  15-MAY-13 09.59.53.000000000 AM**
  5   B    15-May-13  15-MAY-13 10.12.25.000000000 AM
**5   B    15-May-13  15-MAY-13 10.30.25.000000000 AM**
  1   A    16-May-13  16-MAY-13 01.23.00.000000000 AM
  1   B    16-May-13  16-MAY-13 01.28.35.000000000 AM
**1   B    16-May-13  16-MAY-13 01.28.43.000000000 AM**
  3   A    16-May-13  16-MAY-13 08.38.06.000000000 PM
**3   B    16-May-13  16-MAY-13 12.05.53.000000000 AM**
  4   A    16-May-13  16-MAY-13 12.21.57.000000000 AM
**4   B    16-May-13  16-MAY-13 05.21.57.000000000 PM**
```

The result set should look like below with all the users that had event B, the event date of the last event for the specific day (in case event had multiple records) and date.

```
User Event Event_Date Event_Time
==== ===== ========== =================================
 1    B    15-May-13   
 3    B    15-May-13   
 5    B    15-May-13   
 1    B    16-May-13   
 3    B    16-May-13   
 4    B    16-May-13
```

The below query gives me the correct results for one day but when I try for a range of dates it gives only the most recent event.

```
select user, event, event_date, max(event_time)
from table_A where event = 'B'
and event_date = '15-May-13'
group by user, event, event_date
```

Comment: Did you try removing the `and event_date ='15-May-13'` from your where clause?  Then you will return all dates.  What is the query you are using when you use a date range?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Why do you store `event_date` ***and*** `event_time`. `event_time` is a timestamp that contains the same date as the `event_date` column. Seems quite redundant to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a1.user, a1.event, a1.event_date, a1.event_time
from table_A a1 
where a1.event ='B' 
and a1.event_date <='15-May-13'
and a1.event_date >='01-May-13'
and a1.event_time = (select max(event_time) 
                 from table_A a2
                 where a2.event = a1.event 
                 and a2.event_date = a1.event_date
                 and a2.user = a1.user)
```

The correlated subquery is getting the max time for each row that the main query is retrieving. In this case we are getting the max time for each event, event_date and user.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select username, 
       event, 
       event_date, 
       event_time
from (
    select "USER" as username, 
           event, 
           event_date, 
           event_time
           row_number() over (partition by "USER", event order by event_time desc) as rn
    from table_a
    where event = 'B' 
      and event_date between date '2013-05-13' and date '2013-05-15'
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Note that `USER` is a reserved word, so it needs to be quoted (and for convenience I "renamed" it). I also used ANSI date literals to make date parsing more stable and independent of any language/environment settings.